# Unable to paste a file to '/usr' folder

Tags: permissions, filesystem, copy

I am trying to paste an `install` file into the `/usr` directory, but when I right-click on the file manager in the `/usr` directory, the paste option is inactive and if I try drag and drop permission is denied for my action.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because you do not have permission to write to the `/usr` directory.

```
drwxr-xr-x  12 root root  4096 May 28 17:06 usr/
```

As you see the owner and group of `/usr` is `root`. As a normal user, you only have read and execute (for directories, this means access) permissions. Placing a file here is a write operation, so you will need to perform that action as root.

In Ubuntu we run commands (or programs) as root using `sudo`.

#### GUI method:

```
sudo -H nautilus
```

This opens an instance of nautilus as root. We use the `-H` option (this sets HOME to avoid root becoming owner of local config files, a problem that may arise if you make the mistake of [running graphical applications with normal sudo](https://askubuntu.com/a/270019/550618).

Now you will be able to copy (and delete) files anywhere, so please be very careful.

#### Command line method

Simply use the `cp` command with root access:

```
sudo cp /path/to/your/file /usr
```